# UI automation change default device

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, ios-ui-automation

I have a strange issue.
While I'm executing the project in simulator (on ipad ios 7.1) it runs OK , and each time I open the simulator it open the original device (ipad ios 7.1).
Once I'm executing UIautomation trough the command line , it opens different simulator (iphone ios 6) and since this moment, each time I open a simulator it opens an iphone ios 6.
I'm running xcode 5.1.1

on machine with xcode 5.0.2 everything works fine (the same tests are running on ipad ios 7.1)

Answer (score 1):

Recently with changes to xcode and instruments a flag that used to be optional is now required for running instruments via command line you need to specify the device you want to use.

To get a list of devices you can open a terminal and use the following command.

```
instruments -w l
```

This will print the list of simulators. In the form of

```
(Simulator Name) [Simulator UUID]
iPhone 6 Plus (8.1 Simulator) [E19E1336-183D-4C22-93F3-E8E185A496DF]
```

I've found you can use either the name or the UUID and append your cmd line for the automation test with

```
-w [UUID]
```